# How init change redux state from componentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
componentDidMount(){
    var self = this;

    //selt.props is undefined too from this point !!!! WHY
    //   this.props.addTodo();

    window.onscroll = function(){

         //self.setState({ type:'ADD_TODO' });
        // debugger
         self.props.addTodo('param')
    }


}



function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        todos: state
    };
}

 function mapDispatchToProps (dispatch, ownProps) {



    return {

        addTodo: function(text){
            dispatch({type: 'ADD_TODO', text: text, id: ++_idSeq});
        }

    }

}
```

> self.props.addTodo **is not a function**
>
> self.setState({ type:'ADD_TODO' }); **dont init reducer** ! Why ?

reducer code :

```
function todoReducer (currentState, action) {
    currentState = currentState || {}; // Initial State
    // debugger
    console.log('reducer!');
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            debugger
            let newTodo = {id:1};
            return Object.assign({}, currentState, newTodo);



        default:
            return currentState; // TODO: Always return the state
    }
}



// Create Store
var todoStore = createStore(todoReducer);

let unsubscribe = todoStore.subscribe(() => console.log(todoStore.getState()))

window.store = todoStore;




var TodoListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: could you please, clarify how you project structure is? and what code is in which file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dispatch and action from your `component`and change your state in the `reducer`.

Simple example:

Component:

```
componentWillMount() {
    store.dispatch({ type: 'YOUR-ACTION', payload: 'yourValue' })
}
```

Reducer:

```
function app(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'YOUR-ACTION':
      // change your state here 
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Notes:
Sending directly actions from your component IMO it is not really optimal for real world apps, because you couple your components. Consider instead to use `containers` and decoupling your app more. [An interesting article](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern/).